# dropdown value disappears when select

Tags: angularjs

I have one select  in which I bind data from database by get method.it binds data perfectly in  select.but when I select one of it option .its disappears..any help appreciated.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="MainCategory" ng-options="main.Name for main in MainCategory track by main.ID" placeholder="Select Main Category">
                            <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
```

this is my contoller code

```
 var baseURL = 'http://localhost:50928/api/ProductAPI/';
var MainCategory = [];
url = baseURL + "GetMainCategoryList";
$http.get(url)
     .success(function (data) {
         $scope.MainCategory = data;
         console.log(data);

     }).error(function (data) {
         console.log(data);

     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ng-options` data is `MainCategory` and your `ng-model` is binded to it as well. This means that selecting an options turns your data to one value only - your selected option. In your case you should have a data property, lets say - `categories`.
Like this:

```
ng-options="main.Name for main in categories track by main.ID"
```

In addition you will hold in your controller another property for the selected Category and `ng-model` will bind to it:

```
ng-model="selectedCategoty"
```

Comment: oh.. so there was conflict because of same model name ..it works now.thanks a lot